# Unknown Host Error, is this a registrar problem or a host problem?

Tags: hosting, domain-name-system

I am dealing with a barrel of weasels on this one.  Ad agency registered the domain in mid-August with Network Solutions.  72 hours ago I updated the DNS to point to a host provided by an associate of the client whose credentials are dubious.

The DNS servers are at NETSONIC.NET (NS1 and NS2) and respond to ping no problem.

I can FTP to the server using its IP but the name is no go.  The name is also no go for tracert and ping:

```
tracert voodoobbqfranchise.com
Unable to resolve target system name voodoobbqfranchise.com.

ping voodoobbqfranchise.com
ping: unknown host voodoobbqfranchise.com
```

I called NetSol and of course their tier one guy swears it must be the host but I insist that an unknown host must be a NetSol issue.  Otherwise we'd get somethng like an httpd_conf error after being routed to the Netsonic server.

Am I right?  Is this an issue at the registrar?

TIA

JG

Comment: This is not really an SO question. But, neither ns1.netsonic.net nor ns2 are serving DNS queries for voodoobbqfranchise.com. If you `dig voodoobbqfranchise.com @ns1.netsonic.net` you will see you get a REFUSED error. So it's neither the webhost nor the registrar's fault.

Comment: Sorry to be out of place.  If it is neither the host nor the registrar where is the issue?

Comment: Bad settings at host.  Edit by host fixed this.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an error in the DNS settings at the host.

Comment: Mark the answer, please, so that it doesn't show as unanswered.

Comment: Which settings had the errors?

Comment: @TeofiloIsraelVizcainoRodrig - my apologies.  I certainly should have listed more detail and I no longer can remember.